# Compiling 32 bit assembly on 64bit system (Ubuntu)

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to learn about assembly with the book ["Programming from the ground up"](http://programminggroundup.blogspot.tw/2007/01/chapter-3-your-first-programs.html). The book covers only 32 bit instructions. Is there a way to run the example codes on 64 bit Ubuntu system? I can't understand the stuff on the man page of the GNU assembler but I heard the `-m32` flag should do it. But it's not a recognized option.

How do I get the examples on the book to work with ease?

Comment: Can you give a reference to the book? Or show some samples?

Comment: Link is now given. That first program is the one I'm trying to run.

Comment: I think the best way is to install 32 bit Ubuntu in VirtualBox. There are another options (see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit), but this is really difficult.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When your assembler and linker are x86_64 versions, the options to produce i386 (32-bit) output are

```
as --32
ld -m elf_i386
```

You don't have to use `as` and `ld` just because you're working with assembly code. `gcc` can be used, and in that case you would use `-m32`.

```
gcc -m32 -nostdlib myprog.s -o myprog
```

Answer (score 4):

From the as man page:

```
   Target i386 options:
      [--32|--n32|--64] [-n]
      [-march=CPU[+EXTENSION...]] [-mtune=CPU]
```

I'm not sure if it works, just try `--32` or `--n32`.

(`-m32` seems to ge the corresponding gcc flag.)

Comment: The `--n32` in the man page appears to be a typo for `--x32`. For old code like the stuff in this book, you want `--32`. `--x32` is for newer code that uses x86_64 features but wants 32-bit pointers. When using `as --32` you'll probably also need `-m elf_i386` for the `ld` commands.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Great it works! I'd check your answer if you'd post one. :)
On a side note, is this the recommended way to learn assembly nowadays? I know this book is a bit old, but it seems like a good one. Any 64 bit alternative resource which is just about as good as this book would be helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit PC requires that you "warn" the linker that a 32-bit elf file is coming:

**$ nasm -f elf -g -F stabs eat.asm**

**$ ld -o eat eat.o -melf_i386**

That's what the melf_i386 directive does: It tells ld that the eat.o file is an elf32 linkable object file. The invocation of NASM is the same as you'd use on a 32-bit PC.

Thanks @Jeff Duntemann