# I'm trying to build a simple "hello world" program in the gnu assembler

Tags: windows, gnu-assembler

Here's the code:

```
.text       # Section declaration
    .global _start

_start:
    # Write our string to stdout
    movl $len, %edx
    movl $msg, %ecx
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $4, %eax
    syscall

    # Exit
    movl $0, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    syscall

.data
msg:
    .ascii "Hello, world!\n"        # Our string
    len = . - msg       # Length of the string
```

I use these shell commands to compile and build it:

> as -o hello.o hello.S

> ld -s -o hello hello.o

> ./hello

But when I run it, I get this error message:

> Illegal instruction

I have tried to replace "syscall" with "int $0x80", but then I get this error:

> Segmentation fault

I use Windows 10 64 bit, so, does anyone have any idea of how I can fix this?

Comment: "Windows 10" + "Segmentation fault" = that's not a valid combination. Are you using a VM? Or WSL?

Comment: ebx, eax... I assume you're aiming at 32-bit(?) Linux(??). So `int 80` is probably the better choice, now to figure out what the crash is. gdb will tell you which instruction crashed. Give it a try.

Comment: You may need to force 32-bit compilation with some extra options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429901/compiling-32-bit-assembly-on-64bit-system-ubuntu

Comment: If you wanted 64-bit code, then you would use `syscall` but the arguments are in different registers from what you have.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are running this on x86 Linux e.g. by using WSL (so `int 0x80` is correct), there are two issues:

1. `movl $msg, %ecx` just moves the *value* of msg into ecx (i.e. the first 4 Bytes of `msg`), but you want the adress pointing to the string => use `lea`
2. as already pointed out in the comments, you will neeed to compile it with the `-m32`-flag to compile an x86-executable

So here's a working version of your code:

```
.text       # Section declaration
    .global main

main:
    # Write our string to stdout
    movl $len, %edx
    lea msg, %ecx # load the effective address (=lea) of msg into ecx
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $4, %eax
    int $0x80 # call the Kernel

    # Exit
    movl $0, %ebx
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80

.data
msg:
    .ascii "Hello, world!\n"        # Our string
    len = . - msg       # Length of the string
```

Compile it with

`gcc -o <outputFile> <inputFile> -m32 -no-pie` (replace `<inputFile>` and `<outputFile>`)
And you get your output

> Hello, world!

If you actually want to write this for x86 Windows, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/1029093/5821910 for an example